# Why is there a random 'b' in binary conversion output?

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a conversion script to convert between formats.

When I use binascii to convert a user given ascii string to binary a 'b' appears in the output.
At first I thought it has something to do with the bytes data format that is required but if I try to reverse the process something completely different appears.

```
if encodetooption == 'B':
            encodestring = encodestring.encode()
            encodedstring = bin(int(binascii.hexlify(encodestring), 16))
```

produces this e.g:

```
0b1100001011011000110010101111000
```

can someone explain why that is so and how it can be reversed properly or how it can be done better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the 'b' character do in front of a string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal)

Comment: @khuynh: No, that's a different thing.

Comment: ‘0b’ at the beginning is probably indicating a binary codes value as ‘0x’ is indicating a hexadecimal coded value.

Comment: Yeah I imagined it had something to do with the bases. Is there anything you know about to avoid this or will I have to strip it off ?

Comment: Just strip it using ‘bin(value)[2:]’